# MongoDB - Update/Insert the Array of object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've one collection i.e 'comments', Which contain two fields. Like below -

**Comments -**

```
{ 
  _id: 'unique_string',
  dataVar: [{
    name: {
       type: string
    }, 
    value: {
       type: string
    }
  }] 
}
```

You can assume the collection data is like below -

```
[
  _id: 'xxxxxx', 
  user: 'robin',
  dataVar:  [{
   name: 'abc', 
   value: 123
  }, {
   name: 'bcd', 
   value: 12345
  }]
]
```

Now the problem is - (I'm using mongoose in nodeJS application)
- How to update and insert the data in 'dataVar' ?
- If data is no available then new document should be created.

**Case 1.** 
If user send the post data like

```
{
_id: 'xxxxxx', 
user: 'robin',
dataVar: [{name: 'abc', value: 12345}]
}
```

then after performing query, the above document (whose _id is 'xxxxxx') should be update like below -

```
{
    _id: 'xxxxxx', 
     user: 'robin',
    dataVar: [
        {name: 'abc', value: 12345}, 
        {name: 'bcd', value: 12345}
    ]
}
```

**Case 2.**
If data is not present then new document should be created.

Comment: Can user send multiple values like `dataVar: [{name: 'abc', value: 12345}, {name: 'bcd', value: 333}]`?

Comment: @HardikShah Yes

Answer (score -1):

To update record in mongodb, you can use like

```
comments.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: 'xxxxxx' }, { $push: { dataVar: {$each: [{name: 'abc', value: 123}, {name: 'def', value: 456}] } } })
```

You can use `{upsert: true}` option for creating field in collection if not exist.

For updating record, you have to use sub-schema inside your main schema. So that `_id` field is created in every object of array. So you can uniquely identify object to update inside array.

```
comments.findOneAndUpdate({ "dataVar._id": 'xxxxxx' }, { $set: { name: 'xyz', value: 789 } })
```

In this way, you can update object, which is inside array.

If you don't want to use `_id`, you have at-least one field which contains unique values. So that you can `findOneAndUpdate` that specific object inside array.